# Agregar iconos Font Awesome 5 Free a NativeScript-vue

Tags: nativescript

Estoy tratando de agregar los iconos de la forma descrita en la documentación de NativeScript entiendo que para Vue cambian algunas cosas, esperando funcione de esta forma, lo que estoy tratando de hacer:

- Descargar Font Awesome de la pagina oficial.
- Descomprimir el zip.
- Buscar el archivo fa-brands-400.ttf y guardarlo en la carpeta `app/fonts/`.
- Crear el estilo en el archivo `app.scss`.

  `.far {
     font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", "fa-brands-400";
     font-weight: 400;
  }`
- Crear el llamado en el archivo `app/components/App.vue` de la siguiente forma:

  `<Label text="&#xf019;" class="far"></Label>`

> Todo se ejecuta correctamente el problema es que **no muestra el icono**, en lugar de eso muestra el contenido de lo que se agrega en el atributo `text="&#xf019;"`.